# Android AsyncTask status looping

Tags: android, database, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask posting data into a sql db, and then im fetching that data from the activity.

Problem is, because the database is empty when the app first launches it will crash trying to fetch stuff from it. So i tried to make a while() loop that will make the activity wait until the AsyncTask is done, and then fetch the data. All i get is a white screen and after a few seconds a "not responding" dialog:

```
    MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(this, country, img);
    task.execute(); 

    SetSql mydb = new SetSql(this);
    mydb.open();

    while(task.getStatus()!=AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
        //wait
    }

    countryCode = mydb.getLatestCode();
    Log.e("debug", countryCode);
    mydb.close();
```

The reason im using the database anyway is because i couldn't figure out a way to send a simple string back from my AsyncTask, is there a way to do that from the postExecute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could make your own onTaskDone interface, like this:

```
public class TaskTest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    interface TaskDoneListener {
        abstract void onTaskDone(String result);
    }

    private TaskDoneListener t;

    public TaskTest(TaskDoneListener t){
        this.t = t;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // do your stuf
        return "some thing";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        t.onTaskDone(result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

You could use the notify and wait functions and use the onTaskDone to notify some kind of Thread that is waiting for a result.

**EDIT:**

execute this code in your onTaskDone method:

```
countryCode = mydb.getLatestCode();
Log.e("debug", countryCode);
mydb.close();
```

**EDIT 2:**

Activity example code:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements TaskDoneListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    TaskTest task;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //create your layout and stuff
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        //Dont start you task in the onCreate this could cause some weird behavior
        //if the onCreate method is not yet done but your task is.
        task = new TaskTest((TaskDoneListener) this, ##country_code?##, ##image?##);
        task.execute();
    }


    public void onTaskDone(String result) {
        //set the results in your created views

    }

}
```

Rolf

Comment: Im sorry, im a bit new to asyncTasks and im not sure how to do this... i just want a simple way to fix my weird loop or send the AsyncTask data to an activity in a simple way..

Comment: Edit made, do you get it now? The Task class i made is an example of course so add your own methods and constructor variables to it. You just can't block your onCreate to wait for data, it's bad.